# Example 1.2 Opera de Cribro

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, sieve-theory

I'm reading the book "Opera de Cribro" by J. Friedlander and H. Iwaniec, and Example 1.2 states

[image: ex 1.2]

Edit: Here $$A(x)=\sum_{m~:~m^{2}+1\leq x}1~~,~~A_{d}(x)=\sum_{\substack{m~:~m^{2}+1\leq x}\\m^{2}+1\equiv 0\pmod{d}}1$$
$$A_{d}(x)=g(d)X+r_{d}(x)$$
and $g$ is a multiplicative function.

I understand that $|r_{p}(x)|\leq 2$ (in fact $|r_{p}(x)|<1$), but I don't get how is the CRT used to get $|r_{d}(x)|\leq 2^{\nu(d)}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\omega(d)$ be the number of solutions to the equation
$$
n^2+1\equiv0\pmod d.
$$
Then we have $|r_d(x)|\le\omega(d)$.
By CRT, we know that $\omega(d)$ is multiplicative, and by the theory of quadratic residue, we also know that
$$
\omega(p)=
\begin{cases}
2 & p\equiv1\pmod4\\
0 & p\equiv3\pmod4
\end{cases}
$$
This means when $d$ is a squarefree integer, we have $\omega(d)\le2^{\nu(d)}$. Hence, the result follows.

Comment: I see, but I feel like this bound is really bad, for example I checked computationally that $|r_{d}(x)|<6$ for all square free numbers $d$ with prime factors up to 50. I thought that $|r_{p}(x)|<1$ could imply a better bound for $r_{d}(x)$.

Comment: @MatíasBruna You don't have to sharpen this bound because $|r_d(x)|\le A^{\omega(d)}$ is already capable of yielding a sharp error term for sieves.